# why std::lock() supports deallock avoidence but std::try_lock() does not?

Tags: c++, c++11

I thought the difference between `std::lock()` and `std::try_lock()`  is only  in `try_lock()` ,  if locks are not available ,  immediately it will return false while in the case of `std::lock()`, it will go in blocked state.

[Cpp reference for std::lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock)

```
void lock( Lockable1& lock1, Lockable2& lock2, LockableN&... lockn );
```

Locks the given Lockable objects lock1, lock2, ..., lockn using a **deadlock avoidance algorithm** to avoid deadlock.

[Cpp reference by try_lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/try_lock)

```
int try_lock( Lockable1& lock1, Lockable2& lock2, LockableN&... lockn);
```

Tries to lock each of the given Lockable objects lock1, lock2, ..., lockn by calling try_lock in order **beginning with the first**.

I have following two questions:

1. Why `std::lock()` provides deadlock avoidence but `std::try_lock` doesn't?
2. why in `std::lock` , order of lock doesn't matter( it could be lock2 , lock 3, lock1, ...) while in `std::try_lock()` order of locks are maintained (lock1, lock2, lock3....)

Comment: I don’t know much about the C++ threading library so I could be very wrong, but my guess is that it’s just that `try_lock` can’t deadlock.

Comment: Additional information to the answers given:  `try_lock`, because it returns the index of the failed lock, [is useful in the implementation of `lock`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/mutex#L409).  The linked libc++ implementation is termed "Smart & Polite" by this [comparison study of the different ways to implement `lock`](http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. Why std::lock() provides deadlock avoidence but std::try_lock doesn't?

It doesn't need to. If the `try_lock` fails to lock all members then it releases all members. You can't get a deadlock from `try_lock` if another thread owns some or all of these resources since you will return immediately.

From `try_lock`:

> If a call to try_lock fails, no further call to try_lock is performed, unlock is called for any locked objects and a 0-based index of the object that failed to lock is returned.

---

> 2. why in std::lock , order of lock doesn't matter( it could be lock2 , lock 3, lock1, ...) while in std::try_lock() order of locks are maintained (lock1, lock2, lock3....)

I suspect because of ease. There is no dead-lock avoidance algorithm required because you either lock all of them, or you can't lock one in which case you release all of them. For this reason the easiest locking approach is to `try_lock` beginning with the first and moving through the variadic template list. Furthermore the return value indicates that it will return the index of the first failed lock. In order to achieve this you must iterate from left to right.

Comment: what about if locks are available, std::try_lock() will return true , can we say that in this scenario ,  it supports  deadlock avoidance?

Comment: @Alok The try_lock does yes. If another thread also uses try_lock then if it cannot get a hold of any one lock, it will fail and unlock all. So you can never get into a deadlock.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is simple. `std::try_lock` does not need deadlock avoidance mechanism, as it will return immediately if a particular lock is not available and unlock all the locks which were obtained. On the other hand, `std::lock()` should only return once all the locks are acquired and will have them locked - and this is why it needs deadlock avoidance.

Consider the case of 2 locks A and B. Let's say, thread 2 owns the lock B, and desires to lock A. At the same time, thread 1 wants to lock A and B. With `std::try_lock` called at thread 1, what is going to happen is that A is successfully locked, a failed attempt to lock B is made, after which A is unlocked (and function return false) - and thread 2 successfuly locks A.

On the other hand, if a `std::lock` would not use deadlock avoidance, and thread 1 were to call it, the sequence of events would be: thread 1 locks A, thread 1 attempts to lock B and is stopped here, thread 2 attempts to lock A and is stopped here. And this point, neither of the threads can make progress and we have a classical deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

2nd Q 1st:

Because `try_lock` is supposed to return the ordinal number of 1st failed lock, but `lock` has to do lock all locks before returning.

1st Q 2nd:

In order to avoid deadlock, the order of locking the locks must be the same among all locking threads. Thus, deadlock prevention involves reordering the inputs in a deterministic and repeatable manor. Where the ordinal of the locks is relevant to the caller, reordering the input cannot take place and deadlock prevention cannot be used.

Comment: Lock ordering is but one algorithm that could be used.  [Here is a study that compares the various algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html).

Comment: The order of locking will yet eventually be unrelated(different) to the order of pushing for the algorithm. But I can see that locking order is not even deterministic. Any more hints before I edit? PS: Thanks for the hint; I really needed it.

Comment: It would be cool to do a survey of current implementation algorithms among gcc, llvm and VS. :-)  When I wrote [Dining Philosophers Rebooted](http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html) 4 years ago it was:  llvm/libc++: Smart & Polite, gcc/libstdc++: Persistent, VS: Persistent.  I don't know what today's implementations do (except for libc++).

Comment: @HowardHinnant I will. But if that is a specific field of your profession, I can happily make a light edit and wait for a full fledged answer from a giant.

Comment: I don't have access to VS, so am unable to perform a complete survey.